# Make a JQueryMobile Table Scrollable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Hey Guys is there a way to make a Table scrollable using Jquery Mobile?
Couldnt find a solution for my purpose.

Lets say i have a table like that:  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u6f3azrh/1/)

```
<table data-role="table" class="ui-responsive ui-shadow gk-decorate testClass" id="someId" is="jqm-table" style="margin-left: %; width: %">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-priority="1">Title_1</th>
        <th data-priority="1">Title_2</th>
        <th data-priority="1">Title_3</th>
        <th data-priority="1">Title_4</th>
        <th data-priority="1">Title_5</th>
        <th data-priority="1">Title_6</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Content_1</th>
        <td>Content_2</td>
        <td>Content_3</td>
        <td>Content_4</td>
        <td>Content_5</td>
        <td>Content_6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Content_1</th>
        <td>Content_2</td>
        <td>Content_3</td>
        <td>Content_4</td>
        <td>Content_5</td>
        <td>Content_6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Content_1</th>
        <td>Content_2</td>
        <td>Content_3</td>
        <td>Content_4</td>
        <td>Content_5</td>
        <td>Content_6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Content_1</th>
        <td>Content_2</td>
        <td>Content_3</td>
        <td>Content_4</td>
        <td>Content_5</td>
        <td>Content_6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Content_1</th>
        <td>Content_2</td>
        <td>Content_3</td>
        <td>Content_4</td>
        <td>Content_5</td>
        <td>Content_6</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

My problem is that i want the Table to only show 5 rows and the rest should be accessible by scrolling. 
Is this Possible to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is sufficient for you, you can set the container div to `overflow:scroll` in y direction and give it a fixed height. To fix the header row, just wrap the content with an addition `<span>` tag and set it to `position:fixed`. Now give the first content row a little space to the top (e.g. as padding) and you are done:

```css
div {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100px;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
thead th {
  position: relative;
}
thead th span {
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
}
table tbody tr:first-child th,
table tbody tr:first-child td {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table data-role="table" class="ui-responsive ui-shadow gk-decorate testClass" id="someId" is="jqm-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-priority="1"><span>Title_1</span></th>
        <th data-priority="1"><span>Title_2</span></th>
        <th data-priority="1"><span>Title_3</span></th>
        <th data-priority="1"><span>Title_4</span></th>
        <th data-priority="1"><span>Title_5</span></th>
        <th data-priority="1"><span>Title_6</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Content_1</th>
        <td>Content_2</td>
        <td>Content_3</td>
        <td>Content_4</td>
        <td>Content_5</td>
        <td>Content_6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Content_1</th>
        <td>Content_2</td>
        <td>Content_3</td>
        <td>Content_4</td>
        <td>Content_5</td>
        <td>Content_6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Content_1</th>
        <td>Content_2</td>
        <td>Content_3</td>
        <td>Content_4</td>
        <td>Content_5</td>
        <td>Content_6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Content_1</th>
        <td>Content_2</td>
        <td>Content_3</td>
        <td>Content_4</td>
        <td>Content_5</td>
        <td>Content_6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Content_1</th>
        <td>Content_2</td>
        <td>Content_3</td>
        <td>Content_4</td>
        <td>Content_5</td>
        <td>Content_6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Content_1</th>
        <td>Content_2</td>
        <td>Content_3</td>
        <td>Content_4</td>
        <td>Content_5</td>
        <td>Content_6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Content_1</th>
        <td>Content_2</td>
        <td>Content_3</td>
        <td>Content_4</td>
        <td>Content_5</td>
        <td>Content_6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Content_1</th>
        <td>Content_2</td>
        <td>Content_3</td>
        <td>Content_4</td>
        <td>Content_5</td>
        <td>Content_6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Content_1</th>
        <td>Content_2</td>
        <td>Content_3</td>
        <td>Content_4</td>
        <td>Content_5</td>
        <td>Content_6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Content_1</th>
        <td>Content_2</td>
        <td>Content_3</td>
        <td>Content_4</td>
        <td>Content_5</td>
        <td>Content_6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Content_1</th>
        <td>Content_2</td>
        <td>Content_3</td>
        <td>Content_4</td>
        <td>Content_5</td>
        <td>Content_6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Content_1</th>
        <td>Content_2</td>
        <td>Content_3</td>
        <td>Content_4</td>
        <td>Content_5</td>
        <td>Content_6</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! that easy. Yea that should be almost enough... the only thing that is missing is that the  Titels(<th></th>) shoud not scroll is that possible ?